# Send data between input boxes in different pages

Tags: javascript, inputbox

I would like to make an inputbox which sends the data to another inputbox in a new tab ( and a new page ) with a button or etc.
I searched for it a lot ( url data transfer & ... ) but still have no idea . 
I appreciate any start point or sth.
Thanks !
Edit : they are different sites with different domains.
Edit 2 : I don't have any accesses to edit the receiver page.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: Have a look at AngularJS.

Comment: I just searched for it but didn't find any clue. :( I'm just a little noob on javascript. @Niels

Comment: Do you want to open a new tab and the inputbox inside this tab should contain the data, or should the data be sent to an existing tab?

Comment: @ref_trumpet It should be sent to a new tab.

Comment: @Donal Thanks ! I've just checked that and I think it should help.

Comment: are the pages on the same domain? there are quicker ways to do this than having a year off learning AngularJs.

Comment: @vsynce No they are on different domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **cross-domain** messaging I would suggest utilizing [**postMessage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_postMessage).

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage) is fair enough, and the API is very very easy:

```
//create popup window
var domain = 'http://scriptandstyle.com';
var myPopup = window.open(domain + '/windowPostMessageListener.html','myWindow');

//periodical message sender
setInterval(function(){
    var message = 'Hello!  The time is: ' + (new Date().getTime());
    console.log('blog.local:  sending message:  ' + message);
    myPopup.postMessage(message,domain); //send the message and target URI
},6000);

//listen to holla back
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
    if(event.origin !== 'http://scriptandstyle.com') return;
    console.log('received response:  ',event.data);
},false);
```

*The above example code was taken from [this article](http://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage) by David Walsh.*

Answer (score 1):

You have millions of options.

You can pass with search parameters , hash, session storage...

[Sender Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnckfzpy/1/)

```
$('#send').on('click', function(e) { 
    window.open('http://jsfiddle.net/cnckfzpy/3/' + "?data=" + $("#sen").val(), "_blank")
});
```

[Receiver Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnckfzpy/3/) (Doesn't work, but the implementation is given)

```
$('#rec').val(window.location.search.split('data=')[1]);
```

Here is used the search parameter approach. but as I said, you have many options to choose from.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. But one thing I have not understand correctly ; Is it necessary for the Receiver Fiddle to be open when you click on the Sender Fiddle or the Sender Fiddle opens the RC Fiddle after clicking on the button automatically?

Comment: the second parameter in the method `window.open`   `"_blank"` is used(it is also a default value, but used here to demonstrate), to open a new blank page e.g a new tab. So yes, the sender fiddle opens the RC fiddle by pressing a button. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: What can I do if I don't have any accesses to edit the RC page ? I mean doing this just by editing the Sender Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

until I know more, I would say localstorage is what you need here:

http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/sharing-messages-and-data-across-windows-using-localstorage/

So one window saves the data (using `JSON.stringify`) and the other window listens to the `storage` event and parsing that data using `JSON.parse`. Also, both window can send and receive together.

And more info here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

And a demo page for 2 tabs - http://html5demos.com/storage-events

Comment: It does not. that is a problem...you didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: Wow that demo is what I want ! But for different sites .. :(

Comment: @Inptbx - So maybe this is what you need - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: That's it ! would you please post it as a answer so that I can mark it as the best answer ? Thanks !

Comment: @Inptbx - just posted my cross-domain answer